# Can PHP process images as matrices like MATLAB?

Tags: php, matlab, vision

I am using matlab in an image processing graduation project , but i don't like it so much provided that i can use PHP easily .

I am asking if PHP can process images like matrices so i can use PHP instead ?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what specifically you are trying to do?

Comment: What did you want to do? Read an image to pixels array?

Comment: What i need is :-
1- Can PHP read an image as a numerical matrix ?
2- Can PHP deal with different colour spaces ( i mean conversion between them ) ?

Comment: There are ImageMagick and GD bindings for php but you need the addons installed to be able to use them, you'll need to check with your webserver for that. But there are ways to do it. One quick google revealed http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php you can just write your own function to build the matrix, but I am no expert so I'll let someone more knowledgeable answer your question propperly. BTW Matlab does this very well, why don't you want to use Matlab?

Comment: Oh I guess that you aren't so much interested in the graphs and such, you just want to use image processing stuff, even still PHP isn't the best alternative...

Comment: I agree that MATLAB is much better than PHP in that , but using PHP i can apply any equation and i can detect errors fast ...etc !

Comment: Why not just call the MATLAB image processing methods from PHP? I'm assuming you eventually want to display processed images / plots on a webpage?

Comment: No , i need to use PHP in image processing instead of learning MATLAB because PHP is easy for me , so i don't want to use MATLAB at all !

Comment: I would suggest you look at imagemagick and GD, it seems that you don't want matlab as matlab is better at other things, there are bindings for Imagemagick and GD for lots of languages, I think that Perl would be a good option, it is not hard to use if you can use php and you don't rely on a webserver etc... and those libraries are designed for exactly the purpose you want, but then you will have to learn it (but it is not hard and you'll be learning image manipulation in php anyway). I use imagemagick in php to create thumbnails for a website gallery so it aint hard =)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you could put your images into php arrays, for example imagine this 1024x768 wallpaper which currently is all white:

```
$width = 1024;
$length = 768;
$myImage = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $width; $i++){
        for($i2 = 0; $i2 < $width; $i2++){
            //        X   Y
            $myImage[$i][$ii] = array(
                'red'   => 0,
                'green' => 0,
                'blue'  => 0,
                'alpha' => 0);
        }
}
```

Now that our image is initialized we can do some colouring, for example lets draw a red vertical line, that is 1 pixel wide and is located at x = 500

```
foreach($myImage[500] as &$pixel){
    $pixel['red'] = 255;
}
```

Now all you need to do is encode your data in PNG.

Comment: Actually i already have image files and i need to convert them to matrices for further processing like Face detection that requires some computations based on numerical matrices representing images , not to generate or draw images .